# Trying to install xubuntu via manual partitioning, need help with the buttons!

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, hard-drive

So I would like to install xubuntu as my sole operating system on Drive C, without losing the contents of the remaining partitions and drives. In the manual partitioning section of the installation, I am able to locate my drive C among the 4 present partitions, but I don't know how to "delete" and "format" this drive, as there are no buttons here with english labels! I'm guessing the minus sign means "delete"? what do the rest of the buttons do? like "create new partition table"? After reading some guides here I'm still not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: If I were a genie then I would see your screen but we are not, so add some screenshot to help the blind!

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen.

Comment: I tried taking a screenshot during installation, but it never prompted me for anything. Could you kindly explain how I can add a screenshot from installation?

Comment: Maybe a search for a install-walkthrough may help. eg. https://www.linuxtechi.com/definitive-guide-to-install-xubuntu-16-04-lts/  where the vm stuff you can skip, or select another.  What me be useful to you is drives won't have labels (C, D, E); each partition is given a mount point (where it loads) where "/"  which is called root is your uppermost directory which is C for most home windoze users.  Data (think D maybe) usually goes in /home  (home directory under "/").

Comment: It may be easier to hit 'try' xubuntu, then use gparted to delete & create (reformat) your /  (C) partition then do install  (usual  format for GNU/Linux is 'ext4' ).  If you leave your other partitions as 'ntfs' (default for windoze) not all file data will get saved due differences; so I'd have another partition as your /home; and just mount your other partitions to other directories, eg. "/other", "/personal" or whatever names fit.  my 2c  (but don't forget to backup first!)

Comment: @guiverc: regarding drive C, do I set the mount point as "/" or "/home"? I would like 4 separate partitions with 4 separate mount points like you've suggested.

Comment: I think C should mount as "/", and the rest should be given directories

Comment: yep.  what you think of as C should be your "/".  If however you're leaving your other partitions as NTFS I'd not use them for /home because they can't store full file info (due ntfs).  Ideally you want a separate partition as /home (allows easier upgrades, even swapping to another gnu/linux easily without overwriting settings), but just let /home be a normal subdirectory under /; and load your ntfs partitions using mount.names that make sense to you (but aren't /usr; /home or directories used by system).  Yes you could use one as /home but it won't be as easy (ie. you'll likely have problems)